# Checking a if a string contains a string value from a dictionary and return the appropriate key

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if a string in a Pandas column contains a word from a dictionary and if there is a match need to create a new column with the appropriate dictionary key as the column value. eg.
dict = {'Car': ['Merc', 'BMW', 'Ford, 'Suzuki'], 'MotorCycle': ['Harley', 'Yamaha', 'Triump']}

df

| Person | Sentence |
| --- | --- |
| A | 'He drives a Merc' |
| B | 'He rides a Harley' |

should return

| Person | Sentence | Vehicle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 'He drives a Merc' | 'Car' |
| B | 'He rides a Harley' | "Motorcycle |

Comment: Can you have more than one match? Can you provide the constructor of the input DataFrame?

Comment: Yes we can have more than one match. Can we add the matches to different columns?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. With my approach you can use `extractall` to get all matches, then aggregate as list or string (please clarify)

Comment: I would want different matches in a list under a named column or under different columns. Would want to know both methods.

Comment: See my updated answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invert the dictionary and use a regex + `map`:

```
import re

dic = {'Car': ['Merc', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Suzuki'],
       'MotorCycle': ['Harley', 'Yamaha', 'Triump']}

# invert dictionary
d = {k:v for v,l in dic.items()
     for k in l}

# craft regex 
regex = f'({"|".join(map(re.escape, d))})'

# map vehicle from match
df['Vehicle'] = df['Sentence'].str.extract(regex, expand=False).map(d)
```

Output:

```
  Person           Sentence     Vehicle
0      A   He drives a Merc         Car
1      B  He rides a Harley  MotorCycle
```

#### several matches:

use `extractall` and either aggregation, or here `unstack`:

```
df.join(df['Sentence'].str.extractall(regex)[0].map(d).unstack().add_prefix('Vehicle_'))
```

output:

```
  Person                     Sentence   Vehicle_0   Vehicle_1
0      A             He drives a Merc         Car         NaN
1      B            He rides a Harley  MotorCycle         NaN
2      C  She has a Merc and a Harley         Car  MotorCycle
```

with aggregation:

```
df['Vehicle'] = df['Sentence'].str.extractall(regex)[0].map(d).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

output:

```
  Person                     Sentence         Vehicle
0      A             He drives a Merc             Car
1      B            He rides a Harley      MotorCycle
2      C  She has a Merc and a Harley  Car,MotorCycle
```

Comment: Thanks to both the answers, I have learnt a new method.

Comment: Works very well. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create reversed dictionary from the `dct` and search for right word using `str.split`:

```py
dct = {
    "Car": ["Merc", "BMW", "Ford", "Suzuki"],
    "MotorCycle": ["Harley", "Yamaha", "Triump"],
}

dct_inv = {i: k for k, v in dct.items() for i in v}


def find_word(x):
    for w in x.strip(" '").split():
        if w in dct_inv:
            return dct_inv[w]
    return None


df["Vehicle"] = df["Sentence"].apply(find_word)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Person             Sentence     Vehicle
0      A   'He drives a Merc'         Car
1      B  'He rides a Harley'  MotorCycle
```

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen your answer